# HTML image render notification

Tags: javascript

In one webpage, I have a big image to load and other contents. Sometimes the image takes longer time to load and I would like to track that. Is there any means by which I can get notified using Javascript when browser completely renders the image?

EDIT

I use the following code to load the image.

```
<table border="0" style="background-image: url(http://abc.com/abc.jpg);" id="imageDisp">
</table>
```

SOME More UPDATE
Is there any simple way to know how long the image took to render? Using the javascript I am getting a notification that the image is loaded now, is there a way to know when the image load started? So that the elapsed time can be calculated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hook on the `load` event of the `<img>` element. E.g.

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/Atlantic_hurricane_tracks.jpg" 
    onload="alert('finished!');">
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ty6JQ/).

---

**Update**:

Then create `new Image()` instead (the average browser is smart enough not to request the same image twice and multiple references will point to the same image request):

```
<script>
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/Atlantic_hurricane_tracks.jpg';
    img.onload = function() { 
        alert('finished!');
    }
</script>
```

[Another jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wVhMd/) (don't forget to clear browser cache, the same image might be already cached :) ).

Comment: The only problem is I use css to load the image as the background image of a table.

Comment: How to use "var image" inside the table tag?

Comment: It's JavaScript. Put it in a `<script>`. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: is there any way I can get to know the the elapsed time - before load and after load time ?

Comment: You can use `new Date().getTime()` to get the current time in seconds. You just call this two times: one immediately in top of page and another in the onload function. Then just substract the one from the other.